# custom popup message after run query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have a anchor tag. Which is for delete rows. If I click on anchor tag then it takes **id** and run query for delete. After that javascript alert box appears for successfully submission message (LOCAL host says:.....). Everything is fine, but I need custom message or modal popup.

**banner.php is (anchor tag):**

```
<?php 
query1=mysql_query("select * from slider_details where banner_id='1'") or die (mysql_error());
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
?> 
<tr>
<td><a class="btn btn-xs bg-danger" href="banner.php?bannerdelete=<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete GIF banner?');"> Delete</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**banner.php (query for delete):**

```
extract($_REQUEST);
if(isset($bannerdelete)==true)
{
$query=mysql_query("delete from slider_details where id='$bannerdelete'") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Deleted Successfully'); </script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='banner.php' </script>";
}
```

In above query, after query alert box appears and then redirect on banner.php
But I don't need javascript alert box.

Comment: DO NOT use `mysql_query` read up on `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: `Everything is fine, but I need custom message or modal popup` This question is way too broad as it stands - you need to decide what you want, try it, then come back if you have issues

Comment: Thank you for reply. how can I go with custom message in popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this https://jsfiddle.net/ndkv3075/6/

here `data-id="10"`  can be replaced by `<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>`

```
a id="myBtn" class="btn btn-xs bg-danger" href="#" data-id="10"> Delete </a>

btn.onclick = function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id= this.dataset.id;
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
          window.location = '<your url>/banner.php?bannerdelete=' + id
      } else {
        swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanyou for reply. But where I will write query?

Comment: the delete portion stays as it is, the above code is only for the anchor tag section

Comment: what about swal() for sweet alert?

Comment: @vinodjaiswal  check it now

Comment: But when I reload page then query runs again. How can redirect it after click on ok button popup.

Answer (score 1):

User jquery UI Dialog Widget

Link: [Click](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Example :

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirm">
  Are you sure?
</div>


$("#dialog").dialog({
      buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
          // todo
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to custom your alert, i recommend this one. [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)

and change your code

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Deleted Successfully'); </script>";
```

to this one.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> swal('Success!', 'File ".$bannerdelete." has been Deleted.', 'success'); </script>";
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But when I reload page then query runs again. How can redirect it after click on ok button popup.

Comment: maybe this one ? `echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
 swal('Success!', 'File ".$bannerdelete." has been Deleted.', 'success')
 .then((value) => {
  window.location = 'banner.php';  // redirect code in here.
 });
</script>";`

Comment: I have made a function echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
       myFn();
      </script>";

Comment: echo"<script type='text/javascript'>

function myFn(){
        swal({
  title: 'Wow!',
  text: 'Message!',
  type: 'success',
  confirmButtonText: 'OK'
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    window.location.href = '//banner.php';
  }
});
}
</script>";

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line dude!

**echo "alert('Deleted Successfully'); ";**

Comment: thank you for reply. But if I delete alert, then how can I show message?